# What is the easiest way to purge all installed ArcGIS Pro AddIns?

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-pro-sdk

I ran the BuildAll.cmd in [arcgis-pro-sdk-community-samples](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pro-sdk-community-samples) and ended up with:
[image]

I need to reverse this temporarily (or permanently and I'll rerun BuildAll.cmd).  What's the easiest way to get back to "factory default"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete the files in C:\Users\user_name\Documents\ArcGIS\AddIns\ArcGISPro

Windows Shell:  `rd "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\ArcGIS\Addins\ArcGISPro" /s`